Is it possible to use Igx-callout-layer with igx-stacked-100-bar-series ignite ui angular data charts?
Is it possible to use Igx-callout-layer with igx-stacked-100-bar-series? if it is possible, can you provide working example?
 <igx-stacked-100-bar-series #bars [xAxis]="xAxis" [yAxis]="yAxis" [dataSource]="item.data">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let child of item.data[0].scaleValues; let i = index">
            <igx-stacked-fragment-series
              outlineMode="collapsed"
              [valueMemberPath]="'scaleValues[' + i + ']'"
              [brush]="dataSource.items[0].data[0]['scaleColors'][i]"
            >
            </igx-stacked-fragment-series>
          </ng-container>
        </igx-stacked-100-bar-series>

I need a working example
